# AzCopy Upload Maxes Out Connection

Tags: azure, blob, azcopy

I have an issue when uploading files to Azure on my server.  Azcopy starts and uploads at the maximum speed of the internet connection, but it maxes it out so much that eventually I can't use remote desktop because it's just taking all the bandwidth.

Any idea how I can limit the amount of bandwidth AzCopy uses?

Comment: Sounds more like network configuration issue from your end, check QoS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try reducing the number of concurrent operations:

> **/NC:"number-of-concurrent-operations"**
>
> Specifies the number of concurrent operations. AzCopy by default
>   starts a certain number of concurrent operations to increase the data
>   transfer throughput. Note that large number of concurrent operations
>   in a low-bandwidth environment may overwhelm the network connection
>   and prevent the operations from fully completing. Throttle concurrent
>   operations based on actual available network bandwidth. The upper
>   limit for concurrent operations is 512.
>
> Applicable to: Blobs, Files, Tables

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-parameters

Answer (score 17):

BTW, in [AzCopy v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10), there's a parameter that lets you directly specify a cap on the amount of bandwidth it uses. E.g. `--cap-mbps 200` will limit it to a max of 200 Mbps.